# How to update model in Django using kwargs

Tags: python, django, model, keyword-argument

I am writing update method for my model:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    @staticmethod
    def update_task(task_id: int, calendar_path: str, **kwargs):
        cal = get_object_or_404(Calendar, path=calendar_path)
        task = get_object_or_404(Task, id=task_id)
        if task.calendar != cal:
            raise FieldError("Calendar does not contains this task")
        for field_name, value in kwargs:
            task
```

I want all fields from kwargs to be renamed, for example like this:
`update_task(..., name = "New Name", description = "New description")`
But I have no idea how to do it, without of using eval, but that is not good idea.

Comment: It's not really clear to me *what* you aim to do.

Comment: I want to create a function that will accept keyword arguments as input and update the task in the database, for example:
` update_task(task_id = 10, calendar_path = "foo", name="New name) ` This code should change task with id = 10 : `task.name = "New name"`

Answer (score 2):

You can work with [**`setattr(…)`** [python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr) and save the `Task` object once we have enumerated over all the key-value pairs:

```
@staticmethod
def update_task(task_id: int, calendar_path: str, **kwargs):
    task = get_object_or_404(Task, id=task_id, calendar__path=calendar_path)
    for field_name, value in kwargs.items():
        setattr(task, field_name, value)
    task.save()
```

A `setattr(x, 'y', value)` is equivalent to `x.y = value`. We can also omit fetching the calendar, by adding this in the filter part with the `get_object_or_404(…)`.

Comment: this is excellent. field_name can be a variable rather than a fixed variable

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using unpacking `*`
Ex:

```
do_it(**{"la":"ga", "gaga":"laga"})
```

is the same as

```
do_it(la = "ga", gaga= "laga")
```

So answer

```
Task.objects.update(**kwargs)
```